# Android Pie: inverted ScrollView momentum

Tags: android, scrollview, android-9.0-pie

My application uses `ScrollView` with `android:scaleY="-1"`.
In phones with Android P the momentum of the scroll is now reverted.

which means that after I scroll down and release - the scrollView continues to scroll up (momentum)

an example can be seen [here](https://github.com/Rongrs/FlatlistBug/tree/master/native_proj/FlatListBugNative)

Maybe it's related to the [scrolling changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28#scrolling-element), but it is not clear what they are

It's important to mention that the same exact app works as expected on older versions of Android

My question is: is this a bug in the new Android version? or that I'm missing some scrolling property in my scrollView?